# how can I set an input range to move only in a given list of values for example 0,30,50 and 90?

Tags: javascript, css

I want my slider to move only on those possible values, currently, it is possible to place the slider on 60, and in this case it should be 50. I just want to get possible values between 0, 30, 50, and 90.

how can do it?

```js
const inputRange = document.getElementById('inputRange');
  
inputRange.addEventListener('input', function() {
  const valor = inputRange.value;
  textSlider=document.getElementById("textRange");
  textSlider.style.left= valor+"%";
  textSlider.innerText= valor + "%";
});
```

```css
.rangeWrap{
    border:1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
#textRange{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background-color: #006cfa;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
}

#textRange:after{
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    top: -4px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 4px 4px 4px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #006cfa transparent;
    z-index:9998;
}
```

```html
<section class="rangeWrap">
    
    <input type="range" id="inputRange" value="0" min="0" max="90" step="30" list="ticks" />

    <datalist id="ticks">
        <option value="0" label="0%"></option>
        <option value="30" label="30%"></option>
        <option value="50" label="50%"></option>
        <option value="90" label="90%"></option>
    </datalist>
    <span id="textRange" >0%</span>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have inserted the code to dynamically detect which tick is closer to the user's dragged/current value. I have added comments to explain what I did. Also I removed the `step` property on input to enable dynamic closest tick value detection.

```js
const inputRange = document.getElementById('inputRange');

const ticksElement = document.getElementById('ticks');
// Get ticks datalist element's childrens (options with values as ticks)
// and extract the tick values as an array such as [0, 30, 50, 90]
const ticks = Array.from(ticksElement.children)
  .map(option => parseInt(option.value));

inputRange.addEventListener('input', function() {
  const valor = parseInt(inputRange.value);
  // Compute the tick value below/before the dragged value (valor)
  const tickBelow = Math.max(...ticks.filter(tick => tick <= valor));
  // Compute the tick value above/after the dragged value (valor)
  const tickAbove = Math.min(...ticks.filter(tick => tick >= valor));
  // Compute the value distance to below/before tick
  const distanceToTickBelow = Math.abs(valor - tickBelow);
  // Compute the value distance to above/after tick
  const distanceToTickAbove = Math.abs(valor - tickAbove);
  
  // Set a variable to hold the tick value which is closer to dragged value (valor)
  let closestTickValue = 0;
  
  // If distance to tick below/before is less than distance
  // to tick above/after, closest tick value is the one below/before
  // Else distance to tick below/before is greater than or equal to 
  // distance to tick above/after, so closest tick value is
  // the one above/after
  if(distanceToTickBelow < distanceToTickAbove) {
    closestTickValue = tickBelow;
  } else {
    closestTickValue = tickAbove;
  }
  
  // Update input's value with closest tick value
  inputRange.value = closestTickValue;
  
  // Update tooltip element's properties with closest tick value
  textSlider = document.getElementById("textRange");
  textSlider.style.left = closestTickValue + "%";
  textSlider.innerText = closestTickValue + "%";
});
```

```css
.rangeWrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#textRange {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background-color: #006cfa;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#textRange:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: -4px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px 4px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #006cfa transparent;
  z-index: 9998;
}
```

```html
<section class="rangeWrap">

  <input type="range" id="inputRange" value="0" min="0" max="90" list="ticks" />

  <datalist id="ticks">
        <option value="0" label="0%"></option>
        <option value="30" label="30%"></option>
        <option value="50" label="50%"></option>
        <option value="90" label="90%"></option>
    </datalist>
  <span id="textRange">0%</span>
</section>
```

Comment: only issue with this approach is it kills keyboard only users ability to change the value

Comment: @epascarello uhm, good point. We can also add keydown handler to detect if the pressed keys are left, right arrow buttons. Depending on the key code, we can directly set input's value the tick after or before the current tick/value. Is there any other available user input/interactions I might be missing other than left or right arrow buttons?

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN can you help me with this similar question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098145/how-can-i-add-several-ticks-for-my-input-range-to-match-the-possible-values-to-b

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to just snap the result to one of the allowed values, which is stored in the const `allowed`. Then you just loop over them in an onchange function and find the nearest one and set the input's value.

```js
const inputRange = document.getElementById('inputRange');
const textSlider = document.getElementById("textRange");
const allowed = [0, 30, 50, 90];

let diff = 100;
let newVal = 0;
inputRange.onchange = function() {
  diff = 100;
  allowed.forEach((val) => {
    let thisDiff = Math.abs(inputRange.value - val);
    if (thisDiff < diff) {
      newVal = val;
      diff = thisDiff;
    }
  });
  inputRange.value = newVal;

  textSlider.style.left= newVal+"%";
  textSlider.innerText= newVal + "%";
}
```

```css
.rangeWrap{
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
#textRange{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background-color: #006cfa;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
}

#textRange:after{
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    top: -4px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 4px 4px 4px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #006cfa transparent;
    z-index:9998;
}
```

```html
<section class="rangeWrap">
    
    <input type="range" id="inputRange" value="0" min="0" max="90" step="1" list="ticks" />

    <datalist id="ticks">
        <option value="0" label="0%"></option>
        <option value="30" label="30%"></option>
        <option value="50" label="50%"></option>
        <option value="90" label="90%"></option>
    </datalist>
    <span id="textRange" >0%</span>
</section>
```