# how can I add several ticks for my input range to match the possible values to be selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do something like this image:

[image]

my possible values are `0, 30 , 50 and 90`

I want to add more secondary ticks and others for the main values which would be `0 , 30 , 50 and 90` (like in the image).

[image]

How can I do it?

note: I have a function that forces the possible values to be `0 30 50 and 90` (especially for the case where you can select `60` and the values go from `30` to `30` but this forces you to select `50` instead of `60`).

```js
const inputRange = document.getElementById('inputRange');

const ticksElement = document.getElementById('ticks');
// Get ticks datalist element's childrens (options with values as ticks)
// and extract the tick values as an array such as [0, 30, 50, 90]
const ticks = Array.from(ticksElement.children)
  .map(option => parseInt(option.value));

inputRange.addEventListener('input', function() {
  const valor = parseInt(inputRange.value);
  // Compute the tick value below/before the dragged value (valor)
  const tickBelow = Math.max(...ticks.filter(tick => tick <= valor));
  // Compute the tick value above/after the dragged value (valor)
  const tickAbove = Math.min(...ticks.filter(tick => tick >= valor));
  // Compute the value distance to below/before tick
  const distanceToTickBelow = Math.abs(valor - tickBelow);
  // Compute the value distance to above/after tick
  const distanceToTickAbove = Math.abs(valor - tickAbove);
  
  // Set a variable to hold the tick value which is closer to dragged value (valor)
  let closestTickValue = 0;
  
  // If distance to tick below/before is less than distance
  // to tick above/after, closest tick value is the one below/before
  // Else distance to tick below/before is greater than or equal to 
  // distance to tick above/after, so closest tick value is
  // the one above/after
  if(distanceToTickBelow < distanceToTickAbove) {
    closestTickValue = tickBelow;
  } else {
    closestTickValue = tickAbove;
  }
  
  // Update input's value with closest tick value
  inputRange.value = closestTickValue;
  
  // Update tooltip element's properties with closest tick value
  textSlider = document.getElementById("textRange");
  textSlider.style.left = closestTickValue + "%";
  textSlider.innerText = closestTickValue + "%";
});
```

```css
.rangeWrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
}

input{
  width:100%;
}

#textRange {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background-color: #006cfa;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#textRange:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: -4px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px 4px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #006cfa transparent;
  z-index: 9998;
}

.o_txt {
  flex: 1;
}
.options {
  width: 30em;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  padding: 0 0 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ticks {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="rangeWrap">

  <input type="range" id="inputRange" value="0" min="0" max="90" list="ticks" />

  <datalist id="ticks">
        <option value="0" label="0%"></option>
        <option value="30" label="30%"></option>
        <option value="50" label="50%"></option>
        <option value="90" label="90%"></option>
    </datalist>
    <div class="ticks">
        <span class="o_txt">Sin pérdida</span>
        <span class="o_txt">30% de pérdida</span>
        <span class="o_txt">50% de pérdida</span>
        <span class="o_txt">90% de pérdida</span>

    </div>
  <span id="textRange">0%</span>
</section>
```

Comment: Try not to confuse the text below with the value within the element - which does appear correct.  Perhaps your issue is that you want the text to sync with the position of what you are calling a 'tick' here?  Positioning a long text below may require you to evaluation your UI somehow

Comment: oh yes! I want the text to synchronize with the position of what I am calling "tick"

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss let's forget about text synchronization, how could I add the "ticks" ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I see 4 main points to address:

- From your question and comments, positioning things seems like your main concern. This could be achieved with [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*);
- To add more ticks, you simply need to [add more options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#adding_tick_marks) to your datalist;
- Assuming the values are to be evenly spaced, you *could* just add a [`step`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#step) attribute (e.g.: `step="10"`) and drop the "closest tick" calculation - just use the value from the input;
- I would strongly suggest that you generate the **elements from an array**, rather than extract an array from the elements, so you can easily update your source of truth programmatically. I'd also store each element as an object, so you can also add some meta information to each of them.

So wrapping everything up:

```js
const inputRange = document.getElementById('inputRange');
const rangeWrap = document.querySelector('.rangeWrap');

const MIN = 0;
const MAX = 90;

rangeWrap.style.setProperty('--min', MIN);
rangeWrap.style.setProperty('--max', MAX);

const ticks = [
  {value: 0, label: 'Sin pérdida'},
  {value: 30, label: '30% de pérdida'},
  {value: 50, label: '50% de pérdida'},
  {value: 90, label: '90% de pérdida'},
];

function initTicks() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.ticks');

  for (const tick of ticks) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = tick.label;
    li.style.setProperty('--value', tick.value);
    container.appendChild(li);
  }
}

initTicks();

inputRange.addEventListener('input', function() {
  const valor = parseInt(inputRange.value);

  const textSlider = document.getElementById("textRange");
  textSlider.style.setProperty('--value', valor);
  textSlider.innerText = valor + "%";
});
```

```css
.rangeWrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  width:100%;
}

#textRange {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background-color: #006cfa;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: calc((var(--value) * 100%) / (var(--max) - var(--min)) - 10px);
}

#textRange:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: -4px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px 4px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #006cfa transparent;
  z-index: 9998;
}

.options {
  width: 30em;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  padding: 0 0 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ticks {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.ticks li {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: calc((var(--value) * 100%) / (var(--max) - var(--min)));
}
```

```html
<section class="rangeWrap">

  <input type="range" id="inputRange" value="0" min="0" max="90" step="10" list="ticks" />

  <datalist id="ticks">
        <option value="0" label="0%"></option>
        <option value="10" label="10%"></option>
        <option value="20" label="20%"></option>
        <option value="30" label="30%"></option>
        <option value="40" label="40%"></option>
        <option value="50" label="50%"></option>
        <option value="60" label="60%"></option>
        <option value="70" label="70%"></option>
        <option value="80" label="80%"></option>
        <option value="90" label="90%"></option>
    </datalist>
    <ul class="ticks"></ul>
  <span id="textRange">0%</span>
</section>
```

### CSS Variables

As I suggested in one of the bullet points above, I used CSS variables to make positioning more dynamic. This excerpt, in particular, might be worth explaining a little further:

```css
left: calc((var(--value) * 100%) / (var(--max) - var(--min)));
```

Because `--min` and `--max` are set to a scope above, they can be accessed by all the inner elements. Basically what's being calculated there can be summarized as `value / range`:

- The reason why we need `* 100%` is to cast `--value` as a `percent` type - it doesn't really "change" the value, but ensures its type is output as a percentage;
- The range itself is the difference between `--max` and `--min`.

---

Note: You may have noticed that the label at the 90% mark doesn't really fit. You may want to [truncate it](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) or add some more container space from the parent.

Bonus note: I didn't tamper with `position` beyond what was strictly necessary, but I suggest you take a look at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning). Where you define as `absolute` and `relative` matters a lot in where things will end up in the screen.